# Can Windows Server AppFabric Caching be used with IIS Express for ASP.NET Session?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, appfabric, iis-express

I would like to run **Windows Server AppFabric Caching** locally on a **Windows 7** machine.

Is it possible to configure an **ASP.Net** app to use **AppFabric Caching** for **session state** with **IIS Express**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, you just need to make sure you have the App Fabric Caching server set up correctly on your local machine.